Embedded C++ classes vs. namespaced free functions
I am using C++ in an embedded environment (ESP32) and have been playing around with different ways of structuring my program. The program isn't super complex but not so simple that it could all be contained in a single main file.
For the purposes of readability I have split the program up into different 'managers', each manager controls one aspect of the program (e.g, serial_manager, ui_manager). Each manager doesn't know about any of the other managers and all communication between them is done through main.
The question I have is how best to implement these managers, and there is one question that I have searched for but haven't found a satisfying answer for. I'm think of taking an object-oriented approach which might look something like this:
Object oriented approach
manager.h
#ifndef _MANAGER_H_
#define _MANAGER_H_

#include <stdint.h>

class foo_manager : public manager
{
  private:
    static const int CONNECT_PIN = 14;
    bool _is_connected = false;
    void on_connect();

  public:
    foo_manager();
    void setup();
    void update();
    bool is_connected();
}

#endif

manager.cpp
#include "hardware_manager.h"

foo_manager::foo_manager()
{
    // some construction
}

void foo_manager::on_connect()
{
 // Do something related to connecting
}

bool foo_manager::is_connected()
{
  return _is_connected;
}

void foo_manager::setup()
{
  gpio_set_mode(CONNECT_PIN, OUTPUT);
  gpio_set_low(CONNECT_PIN);
}

void foo_manager::update()
{
  _is_connected = gpio_read(CONNECT_PIN);
  if (_is_connected)
  {

 }}
}

}

main.cpp
#include "manager.h"


void main()
{
    foo_manager manager;
    manager.setup();
    while (1)
    {
        maanger.update();
        sleep(10);
    }
}

Coming from C I tend to use a 'C+' approach, i.e using the C++ features that improve readability/maintainability but have little to no impact on the program execution, and I don't tend to use classes unless I actually want multiple instances of something or inheritance. Based on this I have used a 'namespaced free functions' approach.
Eg.
Namespaced free functions approach
manager.h
#ifndef _MANAGER_H_
#define _MANAGER_H_

#include <stdint.h>

namespace foo_manager
{

typedef struct {        // Data types defined here
  int a;
  int b;
} example_type_t;


void setup();          // Initialises anything that the manager uses
void update();         // Called regularly to allow the manager to operate

bool is_connected();   // Functions are only exposed if needed by other parts of the program

}

#endif

manager.cpp
#include "manager.h"

namespace foo_manager
{

static const int CONNECT_PIN = 14;

static bool _is_connected = false;      // State defined as static global. Stealing the _prefix from C++ members

void on_connect()
{
 // Do something related to connecting
}

bool is_connected()
{
  return _is_connected;
}

void setup()
{
  gpio_set_mode(CONNECT_PIN, OUTPUT);
  gpio_set_low(CONNECT_PIN);
}

void update()
{
  _is_connected = gpio_read(CONNECT_PIN);
  if (_is_connected)
  {
    on_connect();
  }
}

}

main.cpp
#include "manager.h"


void main()
{
    foo_manager::setup();
    while (1)
    {
        foo_manager::update();
        sleep(10);
    }
}

This could be described as a a sort of singleton class without any of the overhead of the singleton.
Benefits of free functions approach:

Not possible to create a different instance of particular manager

Still has concepts of public (in the header file) and private (in the cpp file)

No need to add overhead by passing instances around

Access to C style function pointer callbacks (for use with gpio or timer interrupts)

This is a key point for me, some of the libraries I am using don't allow an option argument which prevents me from passing a this pointer meaning that I can't have an event driven paradigm (since you can't pass member functions to a C style callback)



Benefits of object oriented approach:

No globals

More common so may be more understandable to a new person reading it (my colleagues come from a python background so tend to have an OO approach to things)


I have generally designed in the namespaced free functions approach and haven't ever had any issues with it. I have just moved to a new organisation and have a colleague reviewing my work and he is unsure that the approach I am taking is in line with best practice (although he has a Python background)

This is a very good analysis that you have made so far and that supports objective decision making. The only problem in the reasoning is an assumption of performance impact which is to be verified.

I'd like to point out that thread-local variables allow to pass arbitrary arguments through third-party single-threaded code and do not have the drawbacks of singleton as they are private.

In short
If you need to to go for readability and maintenability, for example because of safety constraints, use the C++ model with classes, as suggested by your analysis outcome.
If you need to go for performance, for example due to operational concerns, look at what your global optimizer creates as code. If it is not the same and you're still unsure, make a benchmark because premature optimization is the root of all evil.
Some more thoughts
On the power of the global optimiser,  you can compare the assembler generated for both versions online:

Class based code: https://godbolt.org/z/dTWMvT3qG
namespace variant: https://godbolt.org/z/x3acfd7KG

You'd be surprised how close they are!  Just to give some example both versions of setup() are identical, as no local data needs to be accessed therein.  The update() version of the class has a push and a pop more and use indirect indexing, compared of base indexing.
If really this last case would be a performance issue and if really it doesn't really need local instances, you could still opt for making the function static.
I take the opportunity to remind that in C++ it can be int main() but not void main() ;-)

Thanks for the answer! Super interesting to see the differences in the assembler output. The more major concern for me was around the callback aspect as I would like to use interrupts that are expecting C style function pointers. I know that static member functions can be used here but would you say that a static class (i.e, a class with all static members) would be better than namespaced free functions?

I prefer not to give dogmatic answers here. My point of view is that one should always use the most suitable tools for the problem. Classes can help to ensure invariants and implement safer resource management with its destructors and the lifetime rules. Creating classes with only static members sets constraints for future maintenance that will somewhat offset the benefits of the object model. Therefore, if you need to mainly expose functions to outside world and being called back, the namespace with free function seems well suited.

Personally, in view of inevitable maitrnance and evolutions would probably not opt for a "manager" based model but around a request queue and dispatcher, using mainly normal classes, but using a free function for the call back to enqueue the requests, this limiting the time to process an interrupt to the utmost possible. Bit I don't know umtour operating requirements/constraints, so this approach might not be suitable for you
